# Laravel Forge + Laravel-echo-server + Let's Encrypt : How to avoid ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo, laravel-forge

**Introduction**

I got a problem where I have laravel-echo-server running as a deamon on a Laravel Forge server.

The problem is that after sometime, every user got the ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID when echo tried to connect to server. But, my website force https and the page was loading and secure. I verified my certificate date and everything was fine.

After this I finally realise that the deamon supervising `laravel-echo-server start` was running since a long time ago. So I manually restarted it and everything start working fine again.

So, I think the problem is that at first start, laravel-echo-server take the certificate and cache it. Then, if it doesnt have to restart and the current date is later then the valid one, we start getting the error, even if Forge auto renew our certificate, because laravel-echo-server doesnt reload the certificate on renew.

**Question**

How to renew the certificate laravel-echo-server use to avoid getting ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID error?

**Server**

1. Using Deamon on Laravel Forge
2. Using laravel-echo-server
3. Let's Encrypt SSL certificate on Laravel Forge

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to know when Laravel Forge renew our certificate?
The response is [there](https://laravel-news.com/forge-letsencrypt-improvements)

> Forge will automatically start renewing your certificate each Sunday at a random hour and minute to avoid overwhelming the Let’s Encrypt servers.

After this is to know how long a certificate is valid. After using the Google Chrome tool, I found that a certificate is valid for 90 days. I don't have any other source for that.

From that point, forcing a shut down of laravel-echo-server will let our deamon restart it and get the new certificate. A simple schedule job will fix this.

```
//app/Console/Kernel.php
    $schedule->call(function () {
        shell_exec('laravel-echo-server stop');
    })->weeklyOn(1, '1:00');
```

I set the job on Monday at 1 AM. Since Forge do it on random at Sunday, I pick Monday to be sure that the certificate was renewed.

By doing it every week, I'll be sure that my certificate use by laravel-echo-server will never be outdated.